# Regex HTML Codigo Postal

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Estoy intentando realizar un patrón para un código postal, pero no consigo realizarlo. Quiero que sea un numero de 5 digitos que sea entre 01000 y 52999.
El código que tengo ahora mismo es el siguiente:

```
        <input type="text"  pattern="[01000-52999]{5}\d" name="codigoPostalDisco"> <br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres usar SOLO una expresión regular, como está pensado para strings, deberas comprobar los distintos rangos:
de **01**000 a **09**999: **[0][1-9]**[0-9]{3}
de **1**0000 a **4**9999: **[1-4]**[0-9]{4}
y finalmente de **50**000 a **52**999: **[5][0-2]**[0-9]{3}

Quedando la expresión como:
^[0][1-9][0-9]{3}$**|**^[1-4][0-9]{4}$**|**^[5][0-2][0-9]{3}$

Y como indica @Rddevelop se puede reducir extrayendo el **factor común**, obteniendo:
^(0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])**[0-9]{3}**$

Aquí te dejo un test para comprobar que es correcto:

```js
 var re = /^(0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])[0-9]{3}$/;
var out;
for (n=0; n<99999 ; n++){
    numero=n<10?"0000"+n:n<100?"000"+n:n<1000?"00"+n:n<10000?"0"+n:n.toString();
    out=re.test(numero);
    if (n<1000 || n> 52999){
        if (out) {
            console.log("Error :",numero,out);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        if (!out) {
            console.log("Error :",numero,out);
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log("end ", n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bien intentado aunque eso obviamente no controla el rango.

Esto es lo que buscas:

**^(?:0[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|5[0-2])[0-9]{3}$**

**^** : las reglas que vengan despues de este carot tienen que cumplirse al principio del string que se este validando.

**:?** : Grupo no capturado

**0[1-9]** : un numero 0 y otro entre 1 y 9.

**|** : alternativa, OR de regex

**[1-4][0-9]** : un numero entre 1 y 4 y otro entre 0 y 9.

**|** : alternativa, OR de regex

**5[0-2]** : un 5 y luego un numero entre 0 y 2.

**[0,9]{3}** : un numero entre 0 y 9 tres veces.

**$** : fin del string. No puedo haber nada mas después.

Comment: Corregido, quitale el negativo al menos si puede ser para que otros usuarios se beneficien ya que la expresion regular es mucho mas corta que la de la respuesta aceptada y hay un explicacion de cada componente de la expresion.

Comment: Muy bien por agrupar para reducir y muy buena explicación.